# Get number of trained faces in PersonGroup

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is their any API from which we can get the number of person trained in a particular  `PersonGroup` in `Microsoft Face API` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method giving directly the `count` value. But you can use `PersonGroup Person - List` method to know how many `Person` are in your `PersonGroup`.

See example here in `West US` region: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395241

As the site says, the aim of the method is to

> List all persons’ information in the specified person group, including
>   personId, name, userData and persistedFaceIds of registered person
>   faces.

The reply is paged with `start` and `top` parameters:

> Persons are stored in alphabetical order of personId created in PersonGroup Person - Create.
>
> - "start" parameter (string, optional) is a personId value that returned entries have larger ids by string comparison. "start" set to empty to indicate return from the first item.
> - "top" parameter (int, optional) specifies the number of entries
>     to return. A maximal of 1000 entries can be returned in one call. To
>     fetch more, you can specify "start" with the last returned entry’s
>     personId of the current call.